# How to remove [1] in text output from renderPrint in shiny without using renderText

Tags: r, shiny

I've got a shiny app that prints the `aov()` result from the file the user put as input. However, it there are fewer than 2 categories, it should output a sentence giving some feedback. This is the code for this specific output:

```
output$aovResults <- renderPrint({
    if(is.null(tabForm()))
      return(NULL)
    if(length(input$categoriesAOV) < 2)
      return("You should probably select more categories...")
    summary(aov(Value ~ Treatment, tabForm()[tabForm()$Treatment == input$categoriesAOV,]))
  })
```

(For a minimal reproducible example, you should just create the `ui` with `fluidPage()`, add the `verbatimTextOutput("aovResults")` and so on.)

The table `tabForm()` is just a formated reactive version of the inputed file. The problem is that, while it works fine without the second `if()` statement,  this is what I get when there are fewer that 2 categories selected (oh, by the way, `input$categoriesAOV` is a selection of which categories to use):
[image]

I'm sorry I can't actually provide a complete minimal reproducible example, but my full code is over 700 lines long, with a lot of that being toward working with `tabForm()`. This is the most relevant ui, though:

```
tabPanel(title = "One-Way ANOVA",
         h1("One-Way ANOVA"),
         fluidRow(
           column(6,
                  p("This test is to be used when you want to test if 3 or more averages are different."),
                  p(textOutput("shouldDoANOVA")),
                  p("Now let's do your One-Way ANOVA."),
                  checkboxGroupInput("categoriesAOV", label = "You don't have to compare all of them; it can be just a section.", choices = c("Please", "You should enter some data."))
           ),
           column(6,
                  wellPanel(
                    h3("Your results"),
                    verbatimTextOutput("aovResults")
                  )
           )
         )
)
```

(It is inside a navbarMenu).

The reason I keep saying it has to be `renderPrint()` is because `renderText()` doesn't work in the case it actually does print the `aov()` results:

[image]

The bottom line is: how can I get the output to be `"You should probably select more categories..."` instead of `[1] "You should probably select more categories..."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `renderPrint`, I would try:

```
smmry <- summary(aov(......
cat(capture.output(smmry), sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Actually, the `aov()` result printed fine. What I had to do is:
`if(length(input$categoriesAOV) < 2) return(cat("You should probably select more categories..."))`